# Windows client cannot access SMB file share on macOS Mojave

Tags: network, mojave, file-sharing

I am trying to get my Windows 10 PC to access a file share on my MacBook running macOS Mojave. I enable File Sharing on the Mac, give my account read/write privileges to a file share, and enable Windows authentication in System Preferences. Then I go to my Windows PC, and enter `\\10.0.0.202` in the address bar in File Explorer (that's the IP of my Mac, of course). What happens next varies:

1. If Windows authentication is enabled, I get prompted for my username/password. After I enter it, the connection blocks (no visible progress) for ~30 seconds, then gives me a generic "connection failed" dialog. Clicking "show details" gives me an error along the lines of "The semaphore wait timeout has expired".
2. If Windows authentication is *not* enabled, my username/password will not be accepted, despite various Internet sources stating that the Windows authentication flag is only needed for Windows XP-era clients.

I have not found any reason why the semaphore-timeout error occurs; there are no logs that indicate any sort of problem (and I've looked everywhere, from the Console to system.log to running `sudo smbdiagnose` in the Terminal; that last command even captured a packet trace, although I don't have the skills to interpret it). Additionally, the file `/var/log/appfirewall.log` does not exist, even if the firewall is turned on (which it wasn't). Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any possibility that it is a firewall on the Mac?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204445 has some tips if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: What happens if you do \\10.0.0.202\share name\. I've seen issues where I couldnt browse the path but could open the folder.

Comment: Under System Preferences -> Sharing -> under the options button did you select SMB?

Comment: @ThomasNelson: No firewall, and I verified I did select SMB. Furthermore, typing in the share name directly seems to make no difference.

Comment: On your `Mac` open `Terminal` and enter `tail -f /var/log/appfirewall.log`. Next make an attempt to connect on the full path of your shared directory: `smb://10.0.0.202/shared_point` and insert (in your Original Question) the output of the lines which will appear within your `Terminal` window.